# Why this PHP snippet not working?

Tags: php, arrays

```
$i = 'i';
$arr = array('hi' => 'test');
echo "$arr[h$i]";exit();
```

What's the right version to do it without {}?

Say,I know can do it with "{$arr['h' . $i]}"

**EDIT**

> 1.inside ""
>   2.with operation like ".",i.e,['h' . $i]
>   3.without {}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want {}, you'll need to do it this silly way:

```
$idx = "h$i";
echo "$arr[$idx]";exit();
```

Of course, you could also just do

```
$i = 'i';
$arr = array('hi'=>'test');
echo $arr["h$i"]; exit();
```

But I think maybe you oversimplified things for the purposes of your question.

Comment: +1 for "But I think maybe you oversimplified things for the purposes of your question." I'm waiting for the "What are you trying to accomplish?" answer.

Comment: Yeah, exactly.  It seems like Shore is just angry that the parser won't parse what he thinks it should.

Comment: Oh guys,I like doing things inside "",and until recently I come to know that I can access array value without {},but the key can't be a combined one?I ask this question to ensure or deny this.

Comment: Yeah, the parser will choke on that much of a shortcut.  Your only options are to use {}, or get the key into a single variable.

Comment: You already proved it.  Try running your code.  What happens?  A parse error, that's what.

Comment: I might have done it in a wrong way,but doesn't mean there are no way to do it.

Comment: it's just language syntax.  You can do what you want to do, in several ways, which you already know.  As far as I can tell, your question is just "why can't I do it this way", and the answer is because it's invalid syntax according to the php parser.

Answer (score 0):

```
$index = 'h' + $i;
echo $arr[$index];
exit;
```

?

Comment: I also know this version.I mean how to do operations without {}?

Comment: I don't see a single "{" anywhere in meder's answer, do you?

Comment: But there are no operations like "."

Comment: Where are there no operations like "."?  You want a solution that doesn't use "." and doesn't use {}??? Then see my answer.  You want to do it all in one line?  I want a pony.

Comment: That's short hand for "too bad, you can't have what you want".  The point being, I'm not gonna get a pony, and you're not gonna get to be able to write echo "$array[pre$fix]"; and have it work.